# Changing "git status" output colors in Posh-Git

Tags: git, powershell, windows-7, posh-git

In [Posh-Git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git), when I run "git status" in a repository, the colors for changes and untracked files are dark red, when I have tried to configure them to be "normal" red.  I want to do this because I have a console with a dark background, so dark red is difficult to read.

I searched around, and there seem to be two configuration changes which I needed to make:

1. Change "WorkingForegroundColor" and "UntrackedForegroundColor" from "DarkRed" to "Red" in $GitPromptSettings.
2. Change "color.status.changed" and "color.status.untracked" to red in git config.

From my reading, that's all I should need to do, and yet the results of "git status" remain dark red.

Here's a summary, to prove I set them as I claimed, and maybe someone can spot the error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The question is how did this theme, with this colors?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is only one way to change DarkRed to Red here: modify color scheme of console window itself. As far as I know git will pick "first" red on the list (that happens to be dark...). So just increase R value for it.

You can do it directly on window (Properties -> Colors) or in registry. Prompt is different story: it uses PS color names, where Red = Red, not DarkRed...

Comment: This is great. I had no idea that the set of colors in properties was a color palette that everything would draw from.

Comment: I wont lie, I was pretty skeptical about changing the Red from the properties window...but, entirely accurate.  Great answer =)

Comment: Works Great!  Works for Powershell as well if you are using the standard console (not ISE).  And it works for both the git status and posh-git.  I just went to Properties -> Colors, clicked on the dark red and change its Red value to 255.  Works fantastic now.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great help. I have been so annoyed at the red color status info. Has been trying to change it but doesn't work.
Simply making red value to 15 working great to me.

Comment: Running powershell.  Was Most helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: I am deeply frustrated at how byzantine the colour config is in powershell. Really happy to have found this answer!

Answer (score 141):

The output of `git status` is controlled by your .gitconfig file. The default for `changed` and `untracked` files is a dim `Red` but you likely want `Red Bold` which is the bright (default) red you have in the prompt.

Add the following to your .gitconfig file:

```
[color]
    ui = true
[color "status"]
    changed = red bold
    untracked = red bold
    added = green bold
```

For anyone else referencing this in the future, the accepted colours are `normal`, `black`, `red`, `green`, `yellow`, `blue`, `magenta`, `cyan`, and `white` as well a single optional modifier `bold`, `dim`, `ul`, `blink`, or `reverse`. If two colours are given the first is the foreground, and the second is the background.

Comment: Thank you -- my life is now complete!  A note for anyone who may have problems getting this to work, it didn't work for me until I installed a newer version of posh-git.

Comment: This works for any version of git on windows, not just posh git.

Comment: This works even on powershell. +1 for my productivity boost.

Comment: Used the pattern `git config <color-to-update> “foreground-color background-color attribute”` like `git config --global color.status.changed "cyan normal bold"`

Comment: What is ui=true? Check [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration), section colors.

Comment: What is *ul* supposed to do with the colors? I can't tell a difference and it's not immediately obvious. The others are great: +1!

Comment: This is an old answer, color.ui=true enables the invisible formatting characters that colors the output to console. From what I remember, this *used* to be false by default because it wasn't supported on some shells, but it appears that's no longer the case and it's likely unnecessary. With how popular this answer still is I should probably update it at some point.

Answer (score 14):

To change the color of the listed untracked and modified files to the more readable yellow color, you can add this to your ~/.gitconfig file:

```
[color "status"]
    untracked = bold yellow
    changed = bold yellow
```

Also updating you GitPrompt.ps1 to show untracked as yellow is then probably a good idea:

```
    UntrackedForegroundColor  = [ConsoleColor]::Yellow
    WorkingForegroundColor    = [ConsoleColor]::Yellow
```

Edit: GitPrompt.ps1 is found in the PowerShell posh-git folder.

Comment: This is a great answer with far less complexity and 3rd party stuff. It's +1 definitely. However, I'd like to see two more things there. First one being a reference to and a full listing of other properties that are settable in the term of a color (if there are any). Second one is a suggestion how to set an arbitrary color (preferably a hexa-value but a list of available color numerals is great too). The second one is, of course, **if** it is possible (and in my experience, it's a pretty large "*if*".)

Answer (score 14):

In addition of @WarrenB answer. To change the color of status **and** the color of the git diff  (of new lines and removed lines) you have to have this in your .git/config file:

```
[color]
    ui = true
[color "status"]
    changed = red bold
    untracked = red bold
    added = green bold
[color "diff"]
    old = red bold
    new = green bold
```

The "diff" option enables you the bright (bold) red and green colors. Reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-colordiff

Answer (score 8):

You can change these by modifying the source of the GitPrompt.ps1 file in the PowerShell posh-git module folder. I had the same issue and just removed the 'Dark' in the colors defined around line 30 in this file:

```
BeforeIndexForegroundColor= [ConsoleColor]::**Green**
BeforeIndexBackgroundColor= $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor

IndexForegroundColor      = [ConsoleColor]::**Green**
IndexBackgroundColor      = $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor

WorkingForegroundColor    = [ConsoleColor]::**Red**
WorkingBackgroundColor    = $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor

UntrackedText             = ' !'
UntrackedForegroundColor  = [ConsoleColor]::**Red**
```

This list of [Powershell colors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406264.aspx) is also useful.

Comment: This worked for changing the colors on the command prompt which shows the abbreviated status (example: [master +1 ~0 -0 | +2 ~0 ~0]). But it did not change the colors output by the "git status" command. BartekB's suggestion did not change either.

Comment: worked for me in both locations, but only after getting the latest version of posh-git

Comment: worked fine for me with powershell and just standard git from git Bash (what is Posh anyway lol)